# Checking if individual values in df column in range of min and max; extract the row

Tags: python

I have two dataframes.

First, the ICD codes dataframe, including a Min and a Max column that I created.

```
    ICD-Code    Description                                     Min Max
0   A00-B99 Certain infectious and parasitic diseases           A00 B99
1   C00-D49 Neoplasms                                           C00 D49
2   D50-D89 Diseases of the blood and blood-forming organs...   D50 D89
3   E00-E89 Endocrine, nutritional and metabolic diseases       E00 E89
4   F01-F99 Mental, Behavioral and Neurodevelopmental diso...   F01 F99
5   G00-G99 Diseases of the nervous system                      G00 G99
...
```

The other contains information for multiple genetic variants, including a column containing ICD-Codes associated with the variant. Here I only care about TraitID. In this dataframe I have split the TraitID by the dash (-), for example [C00, C14], in each cell.

```
CHR BP          Lead_SNP        Lead_SNP_P      TraitID   
5   105624305   rs549957241     4.320000e-09    C00-C14
...
```

I want to write a script to identify in which of the ICD ranges each of the TraitIDs fall. [C00, C14] would fall into the 'Neoplasms' category.

I want to match the Min and Max values with each TraitID value and assign to them the matching 'Description' from the ICD10 df.

The code that I have so far is:

```
# New column
df['Description'] = 'NaN'

for i in range(len(df)):
    df_line = df['TraitID'][i:i+1]
    for j in icd10_df.index:
        # Thanks to wjandrea for pointing out the error here. Since the ICD code is already split by -, this line doesn't make sense.
        if '-' in df_line and icd10_df.at[j,'Min'] <= df_line <= icd10_df.at[j,'Max']:
            df['Description'] = icd10_df.at[j,'Description']
            print("Say something!")
```

It doesn't return anything...

---

UPDATE

In summary, I have a df that contains a column with ranges of ICD10 codes (eg [C00, C14]). I want to check each line against a table of ICD10 code ranges and check in which ICD10 range each of my codes fall.

```
# Add new column to append Description values from icd10_df
df['Description'] = 'NaN'

for i in df.index:
    df_line = df.at[i,'TraitID']
    for j in icd10_df.index:
        # Check if the cell contains a list, and check in which
        # icd10 range the value at position 0 is. 
        if isinstance(df_line, list) and icd10_df.at[j,'Min'] <= df_line[0] <= icd10_df.at[j,'Max']:
            # Add the ICD10 description to the df dataframe
            df.at[i,'Description'] = icd10_df.at[j,'Description']
```

This is not a very elegant way of writing code, but it works. However, if someone found a more efficient way of doing it, I would appreciate knowing how.

Comment: `'-' in df_line`? Is that supposed to be there? You wrote that you split by the dash but the `df` example still has it.

Comment: Okay, let me clarify that! I am selecting here only the cells that contain - while ignoring others that don't.

Comment: Geez...you're right. I missed that. Now I have to go back and see how to filter these rows. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: You'll also want to fix `df['Description'] = icd10_df...`

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realized, `'-' in df_line` checks the *index* because `df_line` is a `Series`, not a datum. Why are you using slicing anyway? And wouldn't it be easier to use `df['TraitID'].apply()` anyway? I'm not a Pandas expert.